# JavaFX location required, cannot find file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am developing an JavaFX application. It is at its most elementary stages. But I keep getting a strange error, which i cannot manage to fix. I have looked online, and have followed the recommendations. But, the issue is so basic, that i cannot understand what could possibly be the issue. It keeps telling me that the location is required, even though the location is correct and specified.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
```

It points to the `Parent root....` line for this.

Here is the code i use to load the fxml document:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
  Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ScheduleView.fxml"));
  primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
  primaryStage.setTitle("Scheduler");
  primaryStage.show();
}
```

Note that the above code is located in the schedule driver class.

Below is the file struture

[image: This is the file structure of the project]

I have tried creating a separate JavaFX project with the exact same FX code/documents, and it works. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have your tried a clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes, the issue remains.

Comment: If you would have maven as dependency management I could help, but I have no idea how can it be done in gradle :(

Comment: The easiest but ugly solution would be to move the `.fxml` file to the resources folder, there is a better solution to tell the build that such files like `.fxml` must be treated like they are in the resources folder, that can be easy done in maven, i think there should be a similar solution in gradle too. If you know both maven and gradle, I can show you the maven code then you can convert it to gradle if it is posible.

Comment: @Sunflame I don't think it is ugly solution. Images should be in resources folder.

Comment: @Vanguard I think it is better to keep the `.fxml` file in that package where the controller, it belongs to, is.

Answer (score 1):

put your fxml file into *src/main/resources* directory.

And load it with (added a slash):

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/ScheduleView.fxml"));
```

The directory *src/main/java* is not on the classpath.

Comment: This won't work since if you have a dependency manager like maven or gradle it creates you a resources folder, and the `getClass().getResource(...)` is tying to get the file from the `resources` folder

Comment: @Sunflame wrong. maven takes the content of _src/main/resources_ and put it during the build process into the _target/classes_ folder and that's where the classloader looks for it.

Comment: Ahh sorry, didn't see the first line of your answer, just the highlighted code, and the only difference was the `/`, and if it would be in the same place as it is now it would not work, but you're right in resources it  works. Sorry for my inattention.But besides that it is not a really good solution to separate in resources your `.fxml` files.